# is this invalid C++?

Tags: c++, compound-literals

```
struct HybridExpression {
    RawExpressionElement *ree;
    ExpressionNode *en;
};    

vector<HybridExpression> hexpression;

hexpression.insert(hexpression.begin() + starti, 
        (HybridExpression) {NULL, en});
```

gcc builds without warning but visual studio 2010 wont even compile it.

It doesnt like this bit: `(HybridExpression) {NULL, en}`

Comment: What's the compiler error message?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is using a part of the C programming language that is not included in C++, it's called "compound literal". `g++ -ansi` will diagnose this, saying

> warning: ISO C++ forbids compound-literals

This is **not** a part of C++0x.

The C++0x compatible syntax would have been

```
hexpression.insert(hexpression.begin() + starti, HybridExpression{NULL, en});
```

To quote the C99 standard, paragraph 6.5.2.5:

> A postfix expression that consists of  a  parenthesized
>          type  name followed by a brace-enclosed list of initializers
>          is a compound literal.  It provides an unnamed object  whose
>          value is given by the initializer list.

Comment: @tm1rbrt: you can still rage at them for abandoning C!

Comment: @Cubbi: Did you install Microsoft Visual C?  No, it's Microsoft Visual C++.  They haven't made any pretense at support for the C standard since Microsoft C/C++ Compiler 7.0, which I think was release before C99 was finished.

Comment: @Cubbi, didn't you mean `HybridExpression(NULL, en)`? Note parenthesis, not curly brace.

Comment: @Rob Adams: Round parentheses would have called HybridExpression's two-argument constructor. Curly braces initialize it using the initializer list: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#init-list

Comment: Because of uniform initialization, it will also work without explicitly stating the `HybridExpression` object: `hexpression.insert(hexpression.begin() + starti, {NULL, en});`

Comment: The error shows up under MacPort's GCC 5 with `-std=c++11`, too.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html#C_002b_002b-Extensions, you can use C extensions (including C99 stuff) in C++ programs compiled with GCC.

[Compound literals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Compound-Literals.html#Compound-Literals) is the extension you're actually using.

Comment: compound literals are not included in C++0x, at least as of N3242, and non-constant initializers are not the extension used in this case (they are gcc's extension to the C89 language, not to C++).

Comment: @Cubbi: as the 1st link states, you can use gcc extensions to the C language for C++.

Comment: yes, the first link is good, that's why I didn't downvote. The second one is not relevant. It should have been http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Compound-Literals.html#Compound-Literals

Comment: @Cubbi: Thanks, I did not find it the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid C++ in the current Standard.  I *think* GCC allows it because of a GCC-specific compiler extension.